# Android - Can't populate message from app to facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've used facebook sdk to post on facebook wall. I've create app id in developer facebook and i used following code to post on facebook wall.

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);  
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_actions" };
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", message);
parameters.putString("description", "topic share");

try {
   facebook.request("me");
   String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
   Log.d(TAG, "got response: " + response);       
} catch (Exception e) {       
}
```

The above code is working only for facebook admin account in which the appid contains. If you try to login through some other facebook accounts. its showing following error.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Its asking for public_actions permission, Without review publish_actions will only work for users with a role in our App. I submitted for review but they are telling that Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content. Below are the review comments from facebook team.

[image]

I need to post prefill text on facebook wall. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? I'm working for long time. Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should authorize user firstly with permissions you want to retrieve. What user should post your text on the wall? You didn't choose anyone. Please, try with any tutorial firstly, for example this:

[Tutorial for Facebook SDK](http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first submit your application to Facebook for review.
You need to add [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

then after you can access your application and post on Facebook wall.